# How do you configure Github Desktop to run from the command line in OSX?

Tags: git, macos, github, command-line, alias

I used to be able to do this with the Github GUI app like so:

```
$ github .
```

which would open the current directory in the GUI, but need a new alias or such for "Github Desktop" which is the new GUI app as of Aug 12, 2015.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Within the application, choose `Github Desktop->Preferences` then click the "Advanced" cog/wheel. Then click the button called "Install Command Line Tools" (yes, I know it does *not* look like a button). Then `cd` into a git repo and type `github`. The trailing `.` is not necessary.

P

Comment: `cd` is the command line function to change directories. So if you are at `C:/` and want to navigate to `C:/test` you would execute `cd test`

Comment: this option does not appear to be available for the Windows version of GitHub Desktop.

Comment: In version 0.5.8 of this options appears to be gone T_T

Comment: This no longer exists in the current version

Comment: Answer is out of date.

Comment: As of 0.7.1, they re-added the feature. The "Install Command Line Tools..." is now under the main nav menu though (rather than within Preferences).

Answer (score 0):

on Mac I solved this by uninstalling the beta version and installing a previous official release